# Memory leak when running JQuery plugin function repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have a table which I am using two JQuery plugins on:
Fixed table header: http://www.mustafaozcan.net/en/page/jQuery-Fixed-Table-Header-Plugin.aspx
Column Manager: http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/columnmanager/

These both run fine in conjunction initially with the fixed table header being initially run in the document.ready event handler. However, I have a checkbox which hides/displays a column of the table. Because the fixed table header plugin works by essentially taking a 'screenshot' of the table's header when run, it needs to be run again to take this header change into account. The problem is that every time this is run, it seem to not replace the data already used in the function but instead just add more, resulting in a memory leak. I have tried all sorts of things to try to stop this from happening including:

```
delete header

$('document').unbind('document.ready', 'table.fixedtableheader')

$('table.fixedtableheader').replaceWith(null)

$('table.fixedtableheader').empty().remove()

header.replaceWith($('table').fixedtableheader({headerrowsize:3}))

$('table').fixedtableheader = null
```

All of these (apart from the one using replaceWith) attempt to remove the memory used by the function and then after that I have just run it again. This occurs in chrome, firefox and presumably IE. Does anyone else have any other suggestions?

Comment: Two options I see: send a bug report to the maker of the plugin or find an alternative.  What benefit do you gain from the plugin?

Comment: It fixes the table header so that when you scroll down it always appears at the top of the table. I'll send an email to the maker but posted here because I thought there might be something I've missed in JQuery/javascript that allows you to remove all trace of a previous function call?